# Why does Xpath expression ending in [*] returns empty list when changing to [node()] returns elements

Tags: xml, xpath, predicate

I have an xml file that has a `sortbits` element that has 32 `bit` elements as children. If I use the xpath expression

```
/config/portmod/sortbits/bit[*]
```

it returns an empty list.

if I change it to

```
/config/portmod/sortbits/bit[node()]
```

it returns a `NodeList` with all 32 `bit` elements.

The expression

```
/config/portmod/sortbits/bit[last()]
```

returns the last element. Why doesn't the `[*]` expression return anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `bit[*]` returns bit elements that have a child element. If it returns nothing, presumably there are no bit element that have a child element.

The expression `bit[node()]` returns bit elements that have any kind of child, for example a text node child. Presumably if `bit[node()]` returns elements and `bit[*]` does not, then these elements have a text node child but no element node child.

Comment: Thank you Michael this seems to be the answer. The expression